# GSView Open file's Error: /invalidfileaccess in /findfont

Tags: miktex, ghostscript, postscript, ps

I use GSview to open a `.ps` file and got errors as:

```
GSview 5.0 2012-01-17
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Displaying non DSC file G:/My_Daily Sync/20120404 JSICE/20120402 JSICE2011/JSICE2011.ps
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Medi font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Medi... 3650488 2223609 4329624 3024112 2 done.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal... 3650488 2276491 4349808 3041337 2 done.
Loading NimbusRomNo9L-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusRomNo9L-Regu... 3650488 2328328 4390176 2553455 2 done.
Loading CenturySchL-BoldItal font from %rom%Resource/Font/CenturySchL-BoldItal... 3711040 2393187 4390176 2574118 2 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu... 3771592 2445797 4390176 2748035 2 done.
Scanning c:\psfonts for fonts... 0 files, 0 scanned, 0 new fonts.
Error: /invalidfileaccess in /findfont
Operand stack:
   GothicBBB-Medium-83pv-RKSJ-H
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1926   1   3   %oparray_pop   1925   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1803   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1884   1   7   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1176/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:84/200(L)--   --dict:206/300(L)--   --dict:43/200(L)--   --dict:95/160(L)--   --dict:8/85(L)--
Current allocation mode is local

--- Begin offending input ---
21 mt 4152  121 L
1069 3204 mt 4152 3204 L
4152 3204 mt 4152  121 L
1069 3204 mt 1069  121 L
1069 3204 mt 4152 3204 L
1069 3204 mt 1069  121 L
1069 3204 mt 1069 3173 L
1069  121 mt 1069  152 L
%%IncludeResource: font GothicBBB-Medium-83pv-RKSJ-H
/GothicBBB-Medium-83pv-RKSJ-H 240 FMS
985 3514 mt
(0) s
2611 3204 mt 2611 3173 L
2611  121 mt 2611  152 L
2413 3514 mt
(0.5) s
4152 3204 mt 4152 3173 L
4152  121 mt 4152  152 L
4068 3514 mt
(1) s
1069 3204 mt 1100 3204 L
4152 3204 mt 4121 3204 L
867 3314 mt
(0) s
1069 2587 mt 1100 2587 L
4152 2587 mt 4121 2587 L
639 2697 mt
(0.2) s
1069 1971 mt 1100 1971 L
4152 1971 mt 4121 1971 L
639 2081 mt
(0.4) s
1069 1354 mt 1100 1354 L
4152 1354 mt 4121 1354 L
639 1464 mt
(0.6) s
1069  738 mt 1100  738 L
4152  738 mt 4121  738 L
639  848 mt
(0.8) s
1069  121 mt 1100  121 L
4152  121 mt 4121  121 L
867  231 mt
(1) s

1069  121 mt 4152  121 L
1069 3204 mt 4152 3204 L
4152 3204 mt 4152  121 L
1069 3204 mt 1069  121 L

--- End offending input ---
file offset = 97280
gsapi_run_string_continue returns -101
```

My system is Japanese version Windows 7 64bit with TeXnicCenter + MiKTeX + GSview + GhostScript.

Could you give me any help? I will appreciate for any comments.

Comment: What does the file look like that produced this PS output?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Note that this site is about (La)TeX, which can be used to produce PS files. If your file in question was produced using (La)TeX please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which produces the corrupt PS file.

Comment: `Error: /invalidfileaccess in /findfont` looks like that you are missing a postscript version of a used font.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @lockstep: Done, while this isn't a very good answer IMHO. If this can't be repeated it might be "too localized".

Answer (score 1):

`Error: /invalidfileaccess in /findfont` looks like that you are missing a postscript version of a used font, or at least it is not located in one of the permitted directories. Without further information it is very hard to tell you what caused this. I found https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=402551 where it is stated that you might want to change the option `-dNOSAFER`. Also updating to a newer version of Ghostscript might fix this issue.

Comment: Hmm, the OP used Ghostscript 9.05. That _is_ the latest version! (And also GSView 5.0 is.)

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks, I didn't checked that. Anyway, updating to the next version might fix it (once it is released), at least after the comment in the bug report.